# How to lock LTE_ONLY mode?

Tags: android, android-ndk, qualcomm

I am working on an application that has a requirement to lock the `RAT` on devices. I just want to lock only two modes i.e. `"LTE Only"` or `"WCDMA Only"`.

We can do this without using an app from phone dial app by running *#*#4636#*#* and choosing `Phone Information` and the `"LTE Only"` or `"WCDMA Only"`.
I have also tried `QXDM` to set these values on `NV Item 10` but it doesn't persist on reboot. So if some one have good knowledge of `QXDM` and share that knowledge then it would be really helpful.

My final goal is to do this from Android application that has root access.

Comment: you can't do it with 3rd-party app (your own app) unless it has root permissions

Comment: I have rooted phone.